# How to get screen color depth in asp.net

Tags: java, asp.net, color-depth, bit-depth

I'm working on a website in vb.net 2010 and I need to get color depth of the screen in my default.aspx page. How can I do that? I found this Java code that apparently do what I need, how can I use it inside aspx? Thanks a lot

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

    for (int i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
      DisplayMode dm = gs[i].getDisplayMode();

       int refreshRate = dm.getRefreshRate();
      if (refreshRate == DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN) {
        System.out.println("Unknown rate"); 
      }

      int bitDepth = dm.getBitDepth();
      int numColors = (int) Math.pow(2, bitDepth);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't. It's Java. You'll need to find a VB.Net alternative to the given code. And this Java code refers to screen devices in an OS "forms" context (AWT), not a web based context. There is a Screen class in System.Windows.Forms that you can look at, but, again, it's based on PC forms, not web https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want client information in your server application. The only way to do this is to obtain it client-side and pass it to the server.

The color depth can be obtained in JavaScript in your HTML:

```
var x = "Color Depth: " + screen.colorDepth;
```

Then you will have to find a way to transfer it to your server application.

Comment: ok, screen.colorDepth is working used as a script inside the aspx page, now I have the problem to read the value from the codebehind. I'm trying to write it on a label to be get from codebehind but I can't succeed...